# Loading a PHP file on button click and printing/showing the variables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Basically what i'm trying to do is: 
1. i wrote a php file that connects to my db 
2. i want to load this file into my html "login" page when i press a button.
3. php file is loaded and value of variables are printed.(not using dbfor now)

I tried the following but with no luck:

```
HTML: 
<button id="asd">Load PHP File</button>

JQ:
<script>

$('#asd').on('click',function (e){
    alert('Success');
    $.ajax({
       type:'GET',
       url :"test.php",
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(data) {
           console.log('success',data);
       },

    });
    ajax.send($myJSON);
    e.preventDefault();
});
</script>


PHP:
 if (!isset($myObj))
   $myObj = new stdClass();

 $myObj->name = "John";
 $myObj->age = 30;
 $myObj->city = "New York";
 $myJSON = json_encode($myObj);

 echo $myJSON;
```

I'm fairly new to JQ, AJAX, PHP so exucse my silly coding and question.
So my question is how can I display values from PHP code in my html when the button is clicked?

Comment: `ajax.send($myJSON);` will throw an error because `ajax` is undefined. What's the actual question anyway? Is it why your code doesn't do what you expect it to do? Please read [ask].

Comment: you don't need that line `ajax.send($myJson)` anyway. This is done by jQuery already. Remove that line and test again. Then show us any errors you get (in console, in network tab (the response from test.php)

Answer (score 0):

to display value to html you can use `.html()`, `.append()` to select JSON object from

```
{
   "age": "30",
   "name": "john",
   "city": "New York"
}
```

use `data.keyName` for example `data.name` and to send data to server add

```
data: {key:value, key:value}
```

Try it

```js
$('#asd').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET', // use POST to send data
    url: "http://echo.jsontest.com/name/john/age/33/city/Tasik",
    //data: {
    //  login: "loginname",
    //  password: "pwd"
    //},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      console.log('success', data);
      $('body').append('<p>' + data.name + '</p>');
      $('body').append('<p>' + data.age + '</p>');
      $('body').append('<p>' + data.city + '</p>');
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="asd">Load PHP File</button>
```

Comment: I tried this and still no luck, it gives an error but i'm not sure what it is.

Comment: make sure your server return json header, if not add `header("Conntent-Type: application/json");` on the top